# Abstract classes with inherited interfaces - System.Enum implements IConvertible but MethodInfo.GetMethods() don't list those

Tags: c#, .net, clr, system.reflection

I have searched the ECMA CLR standards as well as MSDN, not to mention several of my .NET / CLR books including Jeffrey Richter's *CLR via C#* and Sergey Lidin's *Expert .NET IL Assembler* for an explanation to what I am seeing.

I understand that System.Enum is an abstract class, so it can potentially have abstract methods with no implementations, but what I am not clear on are the semantics of abstract classes that implement interfaces. I had always understood that any class that inherits an interface must implement that interface, whether the class is abstract or concrete.

In Richter's book it is also stated:

> Any class that inherits the ... interface must also implement all of
>   the methods defined by the interface

Specifically System.Enum confuses me because according to MSDN it *implements* IConvertible

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum(v=vs.110).aspx

An example is ToInt32(), the remarks say: *Uses Convert to perform the conversion.*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb468863(v=vs.110).aspx

But I cannot find these methods with reflection.

As a background, my compiler extracts all of the type information from the .NET builtin assemblies (mscorlib.dll, System.dll. etc.).

This week I flipped a switch to start resolving and checking interface implementations. As soon as I did it starts complaining about unimplemented interface methods for class System.Enum. At first I thought I had filtered out these methods somehow, but I have tested the code without any conditional limitations and the methods do not show up.

MSDN says that System.Enum implements IConvertible. MSDN shows these methods under System.Enum. But looking at the type signature for mscorlib, output from my compiler, Enum doesn't contain ToChar(), ToBool(), ToInt16, ToInt32(), or any others except ToString(IFormatProvider provider). I expected to maybe see abstract methods there, but then again, I don't really have strong expectations because I don't understand what I should see in this case.

Either I am missing these methods with reflection, or they aren't there, or I don't understand this aspect of the CLR or C# (my compiler is not a C# compiler, but it is CTS compliant and uses the standard reflection API via a small utility written in C#).

The section of code is simple. DisplayMethod is responsible for formatting the method declaration, but doesn't otherwise filter or limit the output.

```
MethodInfo[] methods = t.GetMethods();
foreach (MethodInfo m in methods)
{
    if (m.DeclaringType != t) continue;
    if (m.IsSpecialName) continue; // property getters/setters fall under here

    DisplayMethod(m);
}
```

Comment: Regarding the second paragraph of your question, look at this simple experiment: `interface I { void Foo(); } abstract class C : I { }`. This should compile without any errors. Meaning, an abstract class doesn't have to implement methods of the interfaces it "implements". That can be left to derived classes. It doesn't even have to explicitly declare the interface methods as abstract.

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/enum.cs#1073

Comment: @SLaks - Aha! So they are there. Why didn't I think to check the source first. Of course I still wouldn't have known how to access those even if I'd seen that, so it was worth asking the question.

Comment: @stakx - Your experiment is incomplete. Try to derive a concrete class from C and instantiate it. I can instantiate a derivative of System.Enum without implementing IConvertible myself. You can't instantiate class C in your sample, or a empty derivative.

Comment: @MelvinSmith: My comment above was solely made as a response to the following statement of yours: _"I had always understood that any class that inherits an interface must implement that interface, whether the class is abstract or concrete."_ With the "experiment" I tried to show you that this is not so. In that sense it is complete. But I see your point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those methods are implemented explicitly.

To see them in `GetMethods()`, you need to pass `BindingFlags.NonPublic`.

Comment: So I take it BindingFlags.NonPublic means more than just "non public methods" ?

Comment: @MelvinSmith: What do you mean? Note that you also need to pass `Instance` or `Static`.

Comment: I guess you really did literally mean BindingFlags.NonPublic is required for explicit implementations; it took a while to sink in that an explicit implementation of interface IFoo is actually not part of the "public contract" of the type TBar, hence not a "public" member of TBar.

Comment: @MelvinSmith: No; it's simpler than that.  An explicit interface implementation is literally a private method (with an unprintable name) that is mapped to implement the interface.  In fact, VB lets you do that yourself with the `Implements` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

IConvertible is implemented **explicitly**. This means that if you want to access IConvertibe members, you have to cast that enum member to IConvertibe. Here's a sample:

```
 static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine((X.Y as IConvertible).GetTypeCode());
    }

public enum X
{
    Y,
    Z
}
```

Comment: Ok, the light is coming on now. You mean cast it in my reflection code, correct? Because my needs here are actually to declare these methods to my compiler so it can do correct type checking by resolving all interfaces. I wasn't aware that explicit implementations would be hidden from GetMethods()